# Как очищать getStaticProps по запросу с сервера в nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Задача: сохранять данные на front-end с сервера и при запросе пользователя, выдавать готовую страницу (с чем собственно отлично справляется nextjs и getStaticProps).
Но иногда эти данные на сервере изменяются заказчиком и он требует моментального изменения на front-end(срочные правки в текстах или например какие-то акции временные и пр).

В самом nextjs есть API к которому можно обращаться, и впринципе с сервера можно так обращаться к nextjs и выполнять какие-то действия, но собственно что нужно сделать чтобы перегенерировать отдельные страницы?

Сервер можно перезапускать только в определенное время, а заказчик требует изменение данные в срочном порядке. Даже пару минут или даже секунд для заказчика являются важными и терять даже в это время клиентов нельзя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду статически сгенерированные страницы, то в next.js можно их регенерировать по истечении определённого времени с помощью опции revalidate.

[Документация](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration).

```
function Blog({ posts }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li>{post.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

// This function gets called at build time on server-side.
// It may be called again, on a serverless function, if
// revalidation is enabled and a new request comes in
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every second
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  }
}

export default Blog
```

Если данный вариант не подходит, то только переходить на динамический контент загружаемый из бд.